# Django serialize object with information from other model

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

**Current Code**

I have two models (Post and View) as seen below. View is for which user has seen which Post.

Post Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

View Model:

```
class View(models.Model):

    viewer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post.pk)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('post', 'viewer')
```

My views.py currently looks like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@login_required
def get_posts(request):

     posts = list(Post.objects.all())
     data = serialize('json', posts, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
     return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

---

**The problem**

Now I want to be able to serialize many Post objects and add an attribute to each object that says if the user that made the request (`request.user`) has viewed the Post.

Example of result I would like to receive:

```
[
{
    "model": "posts.post",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "creator": ...,
        "content": "This is a sample post",
        "timestamp": "2019-07-07T19:56:07.220Z",
        "viewed_by_user": true <--- I want this attribute
    }
},
{
    "model": "posts.post",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "creator": ...,
        "content": "This is another sample post",
        "timestamp": "2019-07-10T13:04:19.220Z",
        "viewed_by_user": false <--- I want this attribute
    }
}
]
```

Can I achieve this with django serializers? Should I structure my models in a different way?

I am using django-rest-framework for the requests. You can ask me if any other information is needed in order to answer my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using DRF, you should use the DRF serializer classes, not the basic Django ones which are not at all customizable.

Comment: Yes, but I am not familiar with how to use them for this exact problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a standard [`ModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) from DRF:

> serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Post


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    viewed_by_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('pk', 'creator', 'text', 'timestamp', 'viewed_by_user')

    def get_viewed_by_user(self, instance):
        user = self.context['request']. user
        return instance.view_set.filter(viewer=user).exists()
```

And then

> views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
...

from .serializers import PostSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
@login_required
def get_posts(request):
     posts = Post.objects.all()
     serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True, context={'request': request})
     return Response(serializer.data)
```

In your views you can use the newly created `PostSerializer` by providing your current `request` object as a context to the serializer.

After that, you can benefit from [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) in order to display the `viewed_by_user` property.

If you have any additional questions make sure to comment below. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I needed. You forgot the `.user` in `user = self.context['request']` in serializers.py. I made it `user = self.context['request'].user` and it worked !

Comment: @Thanasis1101 Whoops. I've edited my answer, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `DRF` and you don't need a separate model to count users who viewed particular post

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):

    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    viewed_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='viewer')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

**serializers.py**

use a `serializerMethord`  to check if the user viewed particular post

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post


    class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        viewed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = [
                'viewed',
                'text',
                'timestamp'

            ]

        def get_viewed(self, obj):
            print(self.context['request'].user, obj.viewed_by)
            if self.context['request'].user in obj.viewed_by.all():
                return True
            return False
```

then in `views.py`

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializers

    class PostListView(ListAPIView):
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        serializer_class = PostSerializers
```

you can count each views by

```
class PostDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializers

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.get_object()
        data.viewed_by.add(request.user)
        data.save()

        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion with the `viewed_by` inside the Post model. I could use it but it would affect some other functions I use, so I prefer keeping the models as I have them now. But I will keep your suggetsion in mind, in case I need it somewhere else.